# NgTable dynamic sorting depend on column

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I  am using ngTable to show data in table with pagination. 
But Now I want to add sorting on each column.

Does any on have an idea about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at ngTable documentation - [here](http://ng-table.com/#/sorting/demo-sorting-basic) and example [here](http://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/VLROaW)

```
 function demoController(NgTableParams, simpleList) {
    this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
      // initial sort order
      sorting: { name: "asc" } 
    }, {
      dataset: simpleList
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer this 
[Example](http://ng-table.com/#/)

```html
<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
            {{user.name}}</td>
        <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
            {{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

you have to create filter like this.

Likewise you can add serch object name into each column

Comment: Snippet not working. Also, I am looking for sorting not filter.

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks for sharing link.